# Solution to a state equation (differential equation) with final condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We know that the solution to the state equation $\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=Ax$ where A is $n \times n$ matrix and $x(t)$ is a vector $x=[x_1 \ x_2 \cdots x_n]^T$ is given by $x(t)=e^{A(t-t_0)} x(t_0)$, where $t_0$ is the initial time. Now, what if the final condition $t=T$ is given instead of the initial time $t=t_0$? Is it true that the solution is given by $x(t)=e^{A(T-t)} x(T)$?

The reason I'm asking is that I have a system $\frac{dx_1}{dt}=x_2$, $\frac{dx_2}{dt}=-x_1$ with final conditions $x_1(T)=1$ and $x_2(T)=0$. By solving the two differential equations and using the final B.C. I got: $x_1 = cos(T-t)$  and $x_2 = sin(T-t)$. However, by using the formula $x(t)=e^{A(T-t)} x(T)$, I got $x_2 = -sin(T-t)$. Not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: The solution $x(t)=e^{A(t-t_0)}x(t_0)$ holds for positive as well as negative $t$. There is no need to 'correct' any signs by hand, ie. the solution is $x(t)=e^{A(t-T)}x(T)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.